# No reputation points added on upvotes

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation-page

I am having some strange problem with my account on stack overflow. Even though I am getting upvotes for my answer, they are still not getting added to my reputation points.
What is the problem??

Edit: I upvoted some other guys for the same community wiki questions and i see an increase in their reputation points. can somebody explain me this? (lol, i am so crying for reps!!) :P

Edit II: here's the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034758/what-are-the-best-web-design-sites/1421108#1421108

upvote some guys and you will see instant increase in their rep

Edit: ok, i got it cleared. The question was not first marked as wiki so the users who answered prior to this are getting reps added.

Comment: More like status by design

Comment: I was expecting a question - "Is Adit Hallucinating??" with some 100+ upvotes :D :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Votes on a question that is marked as Community Wiki do not increase or decrease reputation.

Votes on an answer marked as Community Wiki do not increase or decrease reputation.

Answers posted after a question is marked as Community Wiki are automatically made Community Wiki and will not gain or lose rep.

Answers posted prior to a question being changed to Community Wiki are not automatically changed over, so they can continue to gain or lose reputation on votes as long as the answer itself is still not Community Wiki.

Comment: now, that's the answer i was looking for. Thanks, mate!!

Comment: Then upvote and mark it as accepted?

Comment: can't upvote..no reps for that..will accept it

Answer (score 6):

> Edit: I upvoted some other guys for the same community wiki questions and i see an increase in their reputation points. can somebody explain me this? (lol, i am so crying for reps!!) :P

You're either hallucinating or they're getting upvoted for other answers they've given. **No reputation is awarded for votes on community-wiki posts**, bottom line.

Comment: you can try it for yourself..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1034758/what-are-the-best-web-design-sites/1421108#1421108

Comment: @Adit: I just upvoted that CW post of yours and it did not increase your reputation. I am starting to agree with the 'Bog's assertion that you are hallucinating.

Comment: @Adit: pay attention!  Not all the answers to the question are community wiki.  Community wiki never gives rep.

Comment: Adit's on some good crack, I guess.

Comment: Adit doesn't have the rep to upvote, and yet he claims to have upvoted some answers. Sounds like he's hallucinating, to me. :-)

Comment: Man, I was talking about stack overflow. I upvoted people there. 
I can't upvote here.

Answer (score 3):

Is the question or answer marked community wiki?

If so there are no reputation for community wiki posts.

Comment: my bad. I missed that point

Comment: The question was  marked as community wiki

Answer (score 2):

Is the question a Community Wiki question? Since those questions do not give you reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Not all of the answers to that question are CW, many of them are still owned by the original answerer, therefore, those users can still earn reputation when their answer is upvoted. Your answer, however, is CW, and therefore you will not receive reputation. The question became CW on [June 24 at 20:06](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1034758/list), all answers after that point are CW, however, the answers provided previous to that point, are not automatically shifted to CW, since this was not turned CW by the community user as a result of 30+ answers being provided.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, how about [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669920/importing-from-text-file-java-question/1669943#1669943) and [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669282/find-max-value-in-java-with-a-predefined-comparator/1669304#1669304)? I got some upvotes, but I didn't get points? The question nor the answer was marked as CW?

Comment: Have you hit the rep cap for the day (200)?

Comment: Hmm, I should have RTFF. I indeed likely exceeded the cap. Why is it there? To demotivate helpful people? ;)

Comment: It's there so people take breaks from the site and that people also don't get crazy rep from one single answer that causes too much inflation.

Comment: Clear, thank you. Just keep helping ;)